# C code, seems to be wrong, don't know why

Tags: c, compilation, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to compile a C file ( I am a begginer), but it says there is some error in the code.

Here's the file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int changenum(int number);

int main() {
    int inital_number = 2;
    changenum(inital_number);
}

int changenum(int number) {
    if (number<3) {
        printf("The number %d is smaller than 3!", number);
    }
}
```

And here's what it says in the terminal:

```
hagaymosko@hagaymosko-Inspiron-5421:~/CCPP/HelloWorld$ gcc -Wall -W -Werror somefile.c -o MyFirstCFile
somefile.c: In function ‘main’:
somefile.c:9:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]    }
^
somefile.c: In function ‘changenum’:
somefile.c:17:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Why don't you google that error, it is pretty clear.

Comment: The error messages say that you are leaving functions that are declared to return a value, but you are not doing it (returning a value that is).

Comment: Why do people keep answering obviously duplicate and easy questions?

Answer (score 1):

'return number' in function changenum

Answer (score 1):

`control reaches end of non-void function` is usually a warning, but since you're compiling with `-Werror`, all warnings are treated as errors: see [the gcc options documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

The warning occurs because you did not return a value in a function defined as `int` (`non-void`): both the `main` and the `changenum` functions are defined as returning `int`, but you didn't place a `return` statement in either.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your functions as returning `int`, but you don't return anything. This is undefined behaviour, and your compiler kindly warns you.

Captain Obvious, over and out.

Comment: LOL. Thank you, I now got that.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying the return value should be int (control reaches end of non-void function) and there is no return statement.

Add a return 0 (or another meaningful int value) at the end of each function

Comment: The comments on the question are right this can easily be found just by googling